# EXC_BAD ACCESS in memcpy

Tags: c, exc-bad-access, memcpy

I trying to build a BST and insert nodes in it. However while creating a new node I keep getting exc_bad access error.What can be the reason? Here is my code:

```
struct Node *node_create(struct BSTree *bst,void *nodeKey, struct Value *nodeVal, struct     Node *rightChild, struct Node *leftChild)
{
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
nodeKey= malloc (sizeof (bst->key_size));
nodeVal = malloc(sizeof(bst->value_size));
size_t sizeKey = sizeof(nodeKey);
memcpy(node->key, nodeKey, sizeKey);  // exc_bad access
size_t sizeVal = sizeof (nodeVal);
memcpy(node->val, nodeVal, sizeVal); // exc_bad access
node->right = rightChild;  
node->left = leftChild;

return node;

}

struct Node {
void *key;
struct Value *val;
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
};



struct BSTree {
size_t key_size, key_alignment;
size_t value_size, value_alignment;
int (*compare_func)(void *, void *);
struct Node *root;
// ... Maybe some other stuff.
};

struct Value {
char name[10];
int id;
};
```

Comment: Can you show your definitions of struct Node, BSTree, and Value?

Comment: I added node, BSTree and value structs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the Node structure, I would guess what you want to do is:

if node is defined as

```
struct Node {
    void *key;
    struct Value *val;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *left;
};
```

then

```
struct Node *node_create(struct BSTree *bst,void *nodeKey, struct Value *nodeVal, struct     Node *rightChild, struct Node *leftChild)
{
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

  node->key = malloc(bst->key_size);          /* No sizeof here */
  node->val = malloc(bst->value_size);
  memcpy(node->key, nodeKey, bst->key_size);  
  memcpy(node->val, nodeVal, bst->value_size);
  node->right = rightChild;  
  node->left = leftChild;

  return node;
}
```

As you don't check for the returns of the `malloc`s (which is a design choice that can e justified), you can even write it simpler that way.

```
struct Node *node_create(struct BSTree *bst,void *nodeKey, struct Value *nodeVal, struct     Node *rightChild, struct Node *leftChild)
{
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

  node->key = memcpy(malloc(bst->key_size)  , nodeKey, bst->key_size); 
  node->val = memcpy(malloc(bst->value_size), nodeVal, bst->value_size);
  node->right = rightChild;  
  node->left = leftChild;
  return node;
}
```

There are people that cringe at this style but I prefer to not dilute my code too much on redundancies.

Comment: Yes, I want to do something like the first one but I have to allocate memory for key and value with size of bst->key_size = (key_sz + key_algn)&(~key_algn-1) and bst->value_size = (val_sz + val_algn)&(~val_algn-1)

Comment: Ok, I changed the code accordingly. As you already have the sizes in bst, you can use them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `Node`, looks like, I'd say, even though you've allocated for `node`, you've not allocated all the members (which appear to be pointers).

Change your code to something like:

```
// Allocate node
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
// Now members
node->key = malloc (sizeof (bst->key_size)); 
// :
```

If you are passing in the key and value, then do a `memcpy` of those values to the above locations. But hard to say without further code...

Comment: In my bst_new function fields of BSTree are initialized and tree is created.

Comment: struct BSTree *bst_new(size_t key_sz, size_t key_algn, size_t val_sz, size_t val_algn, int (*cmp)(void *key1_vp, void *key2_vp))
{
    struct BSTree *bst = malloc(sizeof *bst); 
    bst->key_size = (key_sz + key_algn)&(~key_algn-1);
    bst->value_size = (val_sz + val_algn)&(~val_algn-1);
    bst->compare_func = cmp;
    bst->root = NULL;
    return  bst;
}

Comment: that may be the case, however each `Node` also needs to be correctly allocated and initialized (i.e. the above approach, allocate space for node and then space for relevant members)...

Comment: when you allocate `node`, the `malloc` returns you a block of memory the size of `Node`. The pointers are not initialized to anything useful, you need to set the pointers to point to something, for example `key` is a pointer, but it doesn't point to anything. You need to create space to store the key, and once you've done that, make the pointer point to it... then copy the relevant data.

Comment: doen't this do that for key and value? nodeKey= malloc (sizeof (bst->key_size));
nodeVal = malloc(sizeof(bst->value_size));

Comment: I need to do what you have said but I dont know exactly how to do it

Comment: You've not really said how you are calling or using this function. If your intent is that the parameters (`nodeKey` and `nodeValue` are *output* parameters), you need to change the signature (search for pointer-to-pointer). In this case, you can allocate inside the function as you are doing, and you simply need to change the `node->key` to point to the same location (not the `memcpy`), if you pass in pointers to key and value as parameters, then once you've allocated as above in my answer, then call `memcpy`.

Comment: @user1244069: Note that `sizeof(bst->key_size)` takes the size *of the size*. You want to pass the key size there, not the size of the key size. The same goes for `value_size`.